# Wondering if ASP.NET is RESTful?

Tags: asp.net, rest

I was reading about REST and read that one of its principles is that the web service/application should not track sessions and that it is the job of the clients. Since i know that ASP.NET has session-management, it makes me wonder if it is RESTful. Am i misunderstanding what i read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net is a rich framework offering a large set of capabilities to build any kind of web applications. It's really up to you to decide which features you are using. You can decide to use sessions or not.

Though, REST is not just about sessions...

If you are looking at Asp.Net to build Rest applications, you should look at Asp.Net MVC to build such or even look at the new Asp.net WebApi if you wish to build Rest services.